# Building Vpn - How and where to start

Tags: security, networking, vpn

I want to code a simpe vpn as a part of my course work. I am looking for ways to start. Will be helpful if you guys could help me with resources

Comment: Can you be specific... a site-to-site infrastructure vpn, or something to connect users?  Do you care about the transport (GRE, IPSec, UDP, SSH, SSL...)?  Give us a few more details so we can answer this...

Comment: I would want UDP and I do care about IPSec and I need to use SSL

Comment: CIPE is VPN implemented over UDP... Freeswan is an IPSec implementation... honestly, you should think carefully about your requirements... IPSec and SSL fit the same role in the implementation... I'm not sure how to parse the last response...

Comment: Ok to be honest, I am trying to understand each of these .. So Thats why i need a lot of help.. I am not able to understand a lot of things.. I need basics to advanced stuff.. I am still reading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a basic starting point, you need to be able to write a client/server setup in your language of choice that will transport over IP. Your VPN must also be able to present the operating system with a network interface. If you are using Linux, I suggest the tun/tap system interface. For reference, you could look at the code in qemu which does make use of those OS calls. For the encryption purposes, the OpenSSL library should be able to provide you with all the calls necessary.

I'm not sure what the ultimate requirements of your coursework are. You can build anything from a basic shared-symmetric key setup that can be quickly hacked up to the bottomless pit of trying to build a production worthy VPN system. You should mention your requirements.